# Try to catch a managed PayPalCheckoutSdk.Orders.OrdersCreateRequest error from PHP server in the JavaScript client side

Tags: javascript, paypal, promise, fetch

I want to set up PayPal standard payments with :

- the JavaScript SDK from PayPal, [as explained here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/#know-before-you-code)
- and handling creating and capturing an order from a PHP backend, [as explained here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/create-order/#use-cases)

I use the samples and the code works with a few modifications. I receive the `orderId` from the server and the processing continues on the client side (display of the payment popup, ...)

Now I want to deal with the case when CreateOrder fails on the server side. In this case, I send back an HTTP error code : `header('HTTP/1.1 500 xxxxxx')`

On client side, it's impossible to have error-free processing. I always get an error in the console : 'create_order_error' or/and 'click_initiate_payment_reject'.

I've tried to use the catch function on the promise, or return Promise.reject('xxx'), but nothing does anything about it.

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score -1):

If the createOrder on the server fails, simply don't send back an `id` (or `orderId`, if you are naming your key that) value. Not having an `id` results in error enough, although you can also send back separate, *additional* keys that describe the error condition, such as send back the whole JSON object from the PayPal API (if you want to) for informational purposes. It will be visible in the Network tab and assist with debugging. You don't need to send back an HTTP 500, which may not be appropriate depending on the type of error (a 4xx may be more appropriate), and -- unlike XMLHttpRequest or .ajax() -- fetch ignores such statuses anyway unless you explicitly check `status.ok`

Where you *do* need to more concerned about error handling is in the `onApprove` function, after attempting a capture, as this has business logic consequences. Here is the best JS sample demo of what to do: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thank's for your answer.  
If I don't return a orderID (or an empty value), i have an error in the browser console :  
`click_initiate_payment_reject : {err: "Expected an order id to be passed ..."} `  
I know that onApprove is more important regarding business rules, but I want to make the order creation more robust than in the samples (for example, if my server can't reach PayPal).  
I use HTTP 500 just for testing ;-)

Comment: About yout link, if you modify the fetch url with a unknow url (for example) you will have errors in the console !!! "unhandled_error", "Uncaught Error", "create_order_error", "click_initiate_payment_reject", ... I would like to catch these errors and display a message to the user (e.g. service unavailable)

Comment: There is an `onError` function: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/handle-errors/

Comment: I've test this onError but it only catch errors from fetch, not the errors from buttons

Comment: Errors are generated by the paypal js sdk, not from the js code. That's the reason why I haven't found a solution to catch then, this sdk isn't documented and the sources aren't available

Comment: In the above you are discussing errors from fetch. It will catch those as well as other types of unexpected errors.  I'm not sure what other type of "errors from buttons" you are concerned about that don't get caught (??), but it will not catch expected error messaging such as "Something went wrong"

Comment: The JS SDK has a reference here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/javascript-sdk/javascript-sdk-reference/ , and you can pass `debug=true` as a query string parameter if you need source.

Comment: Fetch is used to get create an order on the PHP backend. If it returns an order ID, all is right. But if the server could't return a right order ID, I have many errors in the console from "buttons:1182:24379" (not visibles by the user). I would by able to "tell" to paypal buttons to stop the process because the server can't get a ordre id.

Comment: I use these documentation but thre's nothing about empty or none orderID returns by the backkend. I will try `debug=true` to get more informations

Comment: With debug=true, I've few more info : smart_buttons_payment_error (buttons:2517:102). But no track to avoid the error. I'm going to stay with errors in the console even if it's dirty.

Comment: Well it is considered an error scenario, and so perfectly normal for those things to be in the console.  FWIW I would zero out the time you are spending on this and invest that time in ensuring your servers will be robust in doing all they can to create an order and return its ID as expected when called

Comment: It's already the case but it can happen that the Paypal server is unreachable. In addition, I learned that developers have to handle errors properly (from backend to frontend). I don’t think managing errors is a waste time, even if in this case I can’t do anything. Fortunately PayPal is only a payment solution ;-)

Comment: Thank's @Preston for your time spended to answer me.

Comment: @JB64 - we've hit a lot of the same issues. Paypal's documentation just isn't that great. Due to the limited scoping available given the iframe, we've decided to just call alert() to let the user know we had trouble with reaching Paypal and we log the error in our backend to investigate later. That's the best we came up with for now.

Comment: What about the documentation should be made clearer? There's an `onError` function if you wish to run some code after the error situation has been propagated back.  Utilize it, or don't. And before going back, if you already know there's an exception situation, you can do anything you want -- including displaying an alert or logging the situation in your backend as David mentions, if that's what you *want* to do. It's up to you. Do what you want.

Comment: It would be nice if we could indicate to the API buttons that the orderId could not be obtained (for example with the value -1 for the orderId).
Concerning the documentation, and to avoid wasting time, it would be nice to know that buttons returns an "error" in the console when the orderId is empty or absent, but that this is normal and unavoidable.

Comment: @PrestonPHX - the onError function is useless, all it returns is text "unable to process transaction". The only place you can actually see the error is in the console; it is not floated up. Part of the problem is that when it errors it returns with a 4xx status code. if this were a jquery ajax call, .fail would catch it; but it does not appear that there is a mechanism in the PP JDK to float this up to you.

Comment: The crazy thing is that in the console you can see the beautifully formed JSON object that has everything you need; but because it is an error, you cannot get to it.  A super easy test is to use; do an authorization twice in a row with the same invoice_id.  About all you can do when you hit an error is throw up and an alert and tell your user 'DOH, sumting happened'. It's frustrating as hell

Comment: How are you doing this authorization twice in a row? If you are calling your server, such as per https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , then you can do your own error handling of the fetch response, including having full access to whatever JSON is propagated back from your server.